# Bootstrap navbar transition not smooth

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML code for my bootstrap navbar.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color:
      rgb(50, 50, 50)">
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbar"
        >

         <h1><i class="fas fa-bars" ></i></h1>

        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
          
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <div>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/SignUp">
                <h1>Sign Up&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/LoginOrDeleteAccount">
                <h1>Login Or Delete Account</h1></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

I tried to change the speed the navbar collapses or expands by using the Css code below.

```css
#navbar{
    transition:height 2s ease;
}
```

The code above works,but the navbar does not expand or collapse smoothly.How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Working Snippet with Bootstrap 5.1 version**

Bootstrap [5.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/)

Please check the following working snippet

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color:
      rgb(50, 50, 50)">
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbar"
      aria-controls="navbar"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
     <h1><i class="fas fa-bars" ></i></h1>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">

      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <div>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/SignUp">
            <h1>Sign Up&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/LoginOrDeleteAccount">
            <h1>Login Or Delete Account</h1></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
      
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Updated Working Snippet with Bootstrap 3.4.1 version**

Note: Toggleable, contextual menu for displaying lists of links. Made interactive with the [dropdown JavaScript plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#dropdowns). Thant's mean you have to call dropdown via javascript

Ex:

```
// Call the dropdowns via JavaScript___
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Please check the following working snippet

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color:
      rgb(50, 50, 50)">
    <button
      type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"
    >
     <h1><i class="fas fa-bars" ></i></h1>
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="navbar"class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <div>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="signUp" href="/SignUp">
            <h1>Sign Up&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/LoginOrDeleteAccount">
            <h1>Login Or Delete Account</h1></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing the button attributes from `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle` and `data-target` to `data-bs-target`

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar">
```